# Unable to locate php5

Tags: 10.10, php, software-sources

when I gave the `sudo apt-get install php5` command it responds with and error message "unable to locate php5"

Comment: Could you please post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's definitely in there (proof below and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/php5)).

```
oli@tim:~$ apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
  Version table:
     5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main i386 Packages
     5.3.3-1ubuntu9 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
oli@tim:~$ 
oli@tim:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
```

Suggestions:

- Is this a new system? Have you run `sudo apt-get update` yet?
- Is your `/etc/apt/sources.list` hopelessly corrupted? At the very least it should have some of the following:

  ```
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
  ```

Answer (score 0):

there is probably problem with your repository configuration...

post here output of

```
more /etc/apt/sources.list
```

php5 is in "main" repository, so you should have there some variant of

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
```

Comment: You need `maverick-security` too to ensure you get the security fixes (**very** important for internet facing services).